# Clones and the characterization of varieties as categories

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

In Grätzer's *Universal Algebra*, he mentions the clone of an algebra at some point, but very quickly and not diving into its properties etc. He mentions that the study of clones has been applied to the characterization of varieties as categories, and this remark sparked my curiosity.

My question is: how precise is that characterization of varieties among categories ? Is it elementary, or very technical ? Has there been progress on this topic since Grätzer wrote his book ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a [variety of categorical perspectives](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/clone) on clones.

For your purpose, the notion of an [algebraic category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+category) and notions derived from it, namely bounded [monadic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadicity+theorem) categories seem to be what you are looking for, though [cartesian multicategories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+multicategory) may also be an interesting place to look.

From the nLab page for algebraic category and the [monadicity theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadicity+theorem#monadicity_over_set): a [concrete category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/concrete+category), i.e. a category equipped with a faithful functor, $U$, into $\mathbf{Set}$ is bounded monadic iff $U$ is monadic and for every $\kappa$-directed colimit for some cardinal $\kappa$, the universal cocone is surjective. For $\mathbf{Set}$-valued functors, $U$ being monadic can be checked via checking that it has a left adjoint and that $U$ creates kernel pairs and equalizers. Every monadic category is the category of algebras for some algebraic variety. A bounded monadic category is exactly a category of algebras for an algebraic variety with at most a set of operations.

Somewhat in the vein of Kevin Carlson's comment, the notion of an [algebraically exact category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributivity+of+limits+over+colimits#sifted_colimits) as a category which has limits and sifted colimits which distribute over those limits. A category of algebras for a variety is algebraically exact. You may find the referenced paper [How Algebraic is Algebra](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n9/8-09abs.html) interesting.

Comment: I don't see clearly how this relates to the problem of characterizing varieties among categories. Could you perhaps expand on this ?

Comment: I guess what I asked wasn't clear enough. If I'm not mistaken, what Grätzer means in those few lines is that the study of clones was helpful in providing properties such that a category satisfies them if and only if it "looks like" (isomorphic to, or equivalent to or something like that) a variety. My question was about those properties, which I called "characterization of varieties among categories".  For instance "has arbitrary products" is a necessary condition that would have to be (a consequence of) one of these properties

Comment: @Max Okay, then I think monadicity and the notion of an [algebraic category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+category) is closer to what you are interested in. Here you have results like: A concrete category (i.e. a category with a faithful functor, $U$, into $\mathbf{Set}$) is monadic iff $U$ has a left adjoint, $U$ reflects isomorphisms, and the category has and $U$ preserves coequalizers of $U$-split pairs. A concrete category is bounded monadic iff it is a category of algebraic varieties.

Comment: I think the issue is that an algebraic variety is not a single model of a theory, but a class of models, which we would think of as a category. Categories of models of Lawvere theories can be characterized as free cocompletions under sifted colimits-that might be the characterization at issue here.

Comment: @DerekElkins : so if I understand your edited post correctly, a category is an algebraic variety iff it is a bounded monadic category; and being a bounded monadic category is expressible in terms of categories and cardinals ?

Comment: @Max You can omit the boundedness constraint and you'll still end up with algebraic "varieties" though they may have a proper class of axioms. Going in the other direction, boundedness may still be too loose, and you may want finitary instead in which case we only consider $\aleph_0$-directed colimits which is to say colimits over a preordered set such that any finite subset has a supremum